# Why does the button size increases as the listbox size gets populated with data?

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm a newbie to c#. I have designed a windows program with button and listbox. The listbox populates the log as the script runs the application. However, as the listbox gets populated with log, the button and label increases which makes the stack panel very ugly?

Any help/advice would be appreciated. Below is my xaml code.

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="0,11,0,5" CornerRadius="5" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="7,10,7,2">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="City" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox Name="City" SelectedValue="Chicago" SelectedValuePath="Name">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Name="btnEnter" Content="Enter" Width="200" Margin="4" Padding="6" Click="btnEnter_Click"></Button>
            <Button Name="btnViewLog" Content="View Log" Width="100" Margin="4" Padding="6" Click="btnLog_Click"></Button>
            <ListBox Name="lbLog"  Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True"  BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"></TextBox>
      </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

Thanks.

Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your Xaml, it is hard to diagnose the problem, so please try to post it with any further questions.  It SOUNDS like it is a horizontal StackPanel, and the elements are all next to each other.

If the orientation of your StackPanel is Vertical, set the HorizontalAlignment on the button to Left, Right, or Center.  If the StackPanel orientation is Horizontal, set the VerticalAlignment on the button to Top, Bottom, or Center.

I'm pretty certain both settings are "Stretch" by default, which means they will try to fill all the space that is available, rather than sizing to their content.

Comment: Thank you Bryan for your quick response. i've updated my xaml code in my question. Can you please look at it and help me out?

Comment: Thanks again, Bryan. Changing the button vertical orientation fixed this issue. Thank you very much.